# how to setup the GLM library in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, settings, glm-math

how do i setup the [GLM Library](http://glm.g-truc.net/) in visual studio 2012?

first i tried extract the glm librar directory to my VS 2012 project directory (the directory containing the glm library is named glm-0.9.4.4). then i tried to add glm-0.9.4.4 to

**PROJECT -> properties -> VC++ directories -> Include Directories**

and then when i tried to use the include `#include <glm/glm.hpp>` in my code i got the following error:

**fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'glm/glm.hpp': No such file or directory**

how do i set up the GLM library correctly to work in my code?

Comment: i never added any library to my visual studio install directory. i added the library to the location of my project (the directory i created the project in)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I succeeded in solving the problem. to add the GLM library to the include path, I did the following steps:

1. Extracted the glm code directory to my project directory (the name of the directory in the archaive downloaded from the internet is glm-0.9.4.4).
   for example if the project is in `C:\projects\myProject` then extracted the glm code to this path (`C:\projects\myProject`).
2. Than I added **the full path** `C:\projects\myProject\glm-0.9.4.4` of the glm directory to:

   > => right click on project in the solution viewer => from the drop down menu choose properties  => C\C++ => General => Additional Include Directories.
3. Add `C:\projects\myProject\glm-0.9.4.4` in the edit box of Additional Include Directories.

Another option if you don't want to use full path for the glm library (or any other library you want to include in you project in general), is to use the path `.\glm-0.9.4.4` instead of the full path (this will work only if you extracted the glm library to the project directory!)

Comment: You shouldn't include all those files. You just needed to include the glm folder inside the glm-0.9.4.4 folder. Everything else is irrelevant for using glm.

Answer (score 3):

GLM is a header-only library, so it's just a matter of getting it to include into your project nicely.

1. Did you actually put the GLM folder in your include path? The folder "glm-0.9.4.4" is not the same as "glm". Basically make sure the path you're trying to include actually lines up.
2. If you're including something in a local (project) directory, use quotes instead of angle brackets to include something. `#include "glm/glm.hpp"`. However if you've told VC to look in the directory where you put GLM, brackets should work. Generally, brackets look in your include path and quotes look in your local path. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) for a better explanation.

Your default include path should look something like `C:/.../Microsoft Visual Studio 12/VC/include`. You can dump it there so it can be accessible to all of your projects if you don't feel like re-copying it to each new project you make. If you *don't* want to do that, find your project directory and place the "glm" folder where all of your other header files are and `#include` it with quotes instead of brackets.

Have you tried snooping around for this on your own? Search for where stdio.h lives or where a folder called "include" is.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just import the whole glm folder into your project and then use quotation to include the glm.hpp file. It's worked with me in the past without worrying much about the header include directories etc.

Comment: By import i actually mean adding the files in your VS project

Comment: Im using visual studio 2012 express and i do this by right clicking on my solution Add->Existing Items

Comment: Ok here's another method i just tried and works out like a charm. First place the glm folder inside your project source directory (wherever you actually store the current project files). After that go to (menu) Project -> Show All Files. then on your right you'll see your solution with 'ghost' files. Everything in your project directory. All you have to do then is right click on that glm folder and click Include in project. And you are done. Then just include your glm.hpp like #include "glm.hpp" or #include "glm/glm.hpp" they should both work

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! i tried what you said and i got a lots of errors. finally i solved the problem and posted it as an answer.

Comment: You probably need to remove dummy.cpp. It includes a main() function. And then it should build just fine